# injecting `sessionScoped` `managedBean` doesn't work

Tags: servlet-filters, managed-bean, managed-property

I have a  `sessionScoped` `managedBean` called `UserManager`, when I try to print `#{UserManager.loggedIn}` in the view, It work, but in my `servlet-filter` the injection of this `managedBean` doesn't work.

I tried to inject it like this:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{userManager}")
private UserManager userManager;
```

And in `userManager` I have null pointer.

Comment: Is this a javax.servlet.Filter? If so, how can it have session scoped fields? It is an application-wide instance that serves all user's requests.

Comment: Yes it's a `javax.servlet.Filter`, I use it to check if the user is not logged in, so I redirect him to `login` page.